# Получить все возможные варианты списков из вариантов из под списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как создать алгоритм, который из списка (с подспиками) с возможными вариантами чисел , число должно стоять на том же id, что и подсписок. Например: список с вариантами:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Ответом должно быть:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [3, 0, 0, 1], [4, 0, 0, 1], [5, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

и так далее

Comment: ответ должен содержать все варианты, а не только то что там указано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
print(list(itertools.product(*l)))

>>[(1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 6),
   (2, 5, 7), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7)]
```

Кортежи можно в списки преобразовать

```
print([list(a) for a in itertools.product(*l)])
>> [[1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7] ...
```